# Emgu CV VideoWriter with specific codec

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv, avi

I need to use the VideoWriter class of Emgu CV library  in order to capture a screen at real time.

what is problem now is the FILE SIZE... so, i have to use the specific codec.

so far i have tried the code im posting:

> // VideoWriter prototype: VideoWriter(String fname, Int32 comprescode,
>   Int32 pfs, Int32 width, Int32 height, Boolean isColor);
>
> VideoWriter captureOutput;= new VideoWriter(@"test.avi", -1, 1, width,
>   height, true);

as a result I got video COmpression dialog which i have a chance to select the codec.

[image]

I selected Microsoft Windows Media Video 9 codec and it seems i need to use this codec in order solve the file size problem.

Instead to select every time when my program runs, I am gonna select it out in my program (in source code).

there are some codec codes can be applied with CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('I', 'Y', 'U', 'V') or others but i dont have any ideas for Windows Media Video 9.

I am just wondering if there somebody faced same problem like im experiencing.

any ideas highly appreciated.
thanks~

Comment: ok, i found it myself :)
captureOutput = new VideoWriter(@"test.avi", CvInvoke.CV_FOURCC('W', 'M', 'V', '3'), 1, width, height, true);

Comment: I'm having similar issues with recording my bitmaps to a file. However, I keep getting an unable to create error when trying to that codec.